# libsodium "Call to undefined function" error

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, libsodium

I have installed libsodium and libsodium-php on ubuntu 16.04 but when I run:

```
`<?php
var_dump([
    \Sodium\library_version_major(),
    \Sodium\library_version_minor(),
    \Sodium\version_string()
]);`
```

I get an error saying:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Sodium\library_version_major()
```

According to phpinfo() Sodium is enabled and the compiled version is 2.0.1 and the library version is 1.0.13. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PHP API for libsodium has changed in version 2.0.0 of the extension.

Originally, all functions were in a `\Sodium\` namespace.

However, following a vote by PHP developers regarding its inclusion in PHP 7.2, it was decided to move everything to the global namespace instead.

So, what used to be `\Sodium\library_version_major()` is now `sodium_library_version_major()`.

Comment: Replacing `\Sodium\library_version_major()` with `sodium_library_version_major()` results in the same error.

Comment: Bad example since that one was replaced with the SODIUM_LIBRARY_MAJOR_VERSION constant. But actual functions now have a sodium_ prefix.

Comment: I also got problems with it, thanks for the answer. Is there an official documentation for those new functions? Apparently they change more function names, since I cannot access ```sodium_crypto_pwhash_scryptsalsa208sha256_str()```. On the libsodium website I can see only outdated examples.

Comment: `crypto_pwhash_scryptsalsa208sha256_str()` doesn't exist any more. It doesn't exist any longer in minimal builds of libsodium either, since there has been a high-level `crypto_pwhash()` API for a long time now. So, use `sodium_crypto_pwhash()`, `sodium_crypto_pwhash_str()` and `sodium_crypto_pwhash_str_verify()`.

Comment: I did the same thing, and it's enabled in phpinfo(). But `sodium_library_version_major()` still get the same error.

Comment: Cool. any idea why it is working but in a bit peculiar way, here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46215938/2037746

Comment: This answer could also help debug which specific syntax you should use, depending on the php/sodium version installed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53956155/php-random-bytes-with-sodium-integer-error

Answer (score 3):

For those who installed Pecl Version of Soidum and Enabled it in php.ini (extension=sodium.so) And Have same error like **Call to Undefined** ...

After Restarting Apache & nginx and lack of success finally Reboot server get sodium work exteremly.

PHP 7.3 & >7.3 = libsodium 2.1

*Hope to be helpful.*

Answer (score 3):

For those who couldnt get the answer working..
thats because it should be:

```
<?php
var_dump([
    SODIUM_LIBRARY_MAJOR_VERSION,
    SODIUM_LIBRARY_MINOR_VERSION,
    SODIUM_LIBRARY_VERSION
]);
```