# Libsodium "Call to undefined function sodium_randombytes_buf"

Tags: php, libsodium

Trying to follow the examples [here](https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/05-publickey-crypto.md), but it gives me

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sodium_randombytes_buf()
```

On top of that, the key pairs seems to be generating weird strings like:

`kÿòjƒFDú{î—4]F◊î¸˜ßˆu…®_•A∞+`.

Is that normal?

Here's my code

```
<?php

// send
$message = 'Hi, this is Alice';
$alice_to_bob_kp = sodium_crypto_box_keypair_from_secretkey_and_publickey(
    file_get_contents('./keys/sec-user-1_box_key.txt'),
    file_get_contents('./keys/pub-user-2_box_key.txt')
);
$nonce = sodium_randombytes_buf(SODIUM_CRYPTO_BOX_NONCEBYTES);
$ciphertext = sodium_crypto_box(
    $message,
    $nonce,
    $alice_to_bob_kp
);




// receive
$bob_to_alice_kp = sodium_crypto_box_keypair_from_secretkey_and_publickey(
    // $bob_box_secretkey,
    // $alice_box_publickey
    file_get_contents('./keys/sec-user-2_box_key.txt'),
    file_get_contents('./keys/pub-user-1_box_key.txt')
);
$nonce = sodium_randombytes_buf(SODIUM_CRYPTO_BOX_NONCEBYTES);
$plaintext = sodium_crypto_box_open(
    $ciphertext,
    $nonce,
    $bob_to_alice_kp
);
if ($plaintext === false) {
    die("Malformed message or invalid MAC");
}
die($plaintext);
```

Comment: You need to require in their files you need

Comment: it's an extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function as `sodium_randombytes_buf()` the code in the example uses `\Sodium\randombytes_buf()`.

Edit:

From the bug history:
"The sodium_randombytes_* symbols have been removed a while back, as PHP now provide similar functions without this extension"

[Bug #74896  sodium's .h defines some functions without .c implementation](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74896)

Comment: They've used the prefix `sodium_*` instead of namespace in the newer version

Comment: You'll need to provide your code to reviev then.

Comment: ok. updated the question content

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: so instead can use `random_bytes()` php built in function? what about the weird `kÿòjƒFDú{î—4]F◊î¸˜ßˆu…®_•A∞+` string generated from the key pairs?

Comment: Well... it is an encrypted keypair so by definition it should look like garbage.

Comment: Keys are binary data. They are not passwords.`crypto_box_keypair()` (as well as all the `keypair()` and `keygen()` functions) generate binary blobs that are not supposed to be printable.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. it works when I use the same `$nonce` value for send and receive. Does that mean in all communication, the recipient must receive the decrypted message and the nonce in order to read the message?

Comment: The nonce is indeed required along with the encrypted message. That nonce doesn’t have to be secret.