# Call to undefined function sodium_randombytes_buf()

Tags: php, sodium

Hello I want to use the sodium_randombytes_buf function on a project that I'm working on. On my machine (docker image) I have installed php 7.2

```
PHP 7.2.9 (cli) (built: Aug 26 2018 05:23:42) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.9, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

pear

```
PEAR Version: 1.10.5
PHP Version: 7.2.9
Zend Engine Version: 3.2.0
```

sodium

```
sodium support => enabled
libsodium headers version => 1.0.15
libsodium library version => 1.0.15
```

and added the following line on composer.json of my project on the section require

```
"ext-sodium": "*"
```

If I run any other sodium function like

```
sodium_crypto_aead_aes256gcm_is_available
```

is working fine. If i try to run the following code

```
var_dump(sodium_randombytes_buf(SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_NONCEBYTES));
exit;
```

I get the following error

> Call to undefined function sodium_randombytes_buf()

Does anyone had similar issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215938/libsodium-call-to-undefined-function-sodium-randombytes-buf

Comment: according to the reply on the answer the added back the sodium_*

Comment: according to php page http://php.net/manual/en/book.sodium.php they removed it. with what function they replaced it?

Answer (score 1):

When Sodium was added to PHP as a core extension, `sodium_randombytes_buf` was not brought along. Instead, you can use `random_bytes` which does the same thing.

```
random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_NONCEBYTES)
```